# Natbib not generating bibliography entries for specific items

Tags: natbib, sharelatex

After some work with an external bibiography file, all bar two entries worked, with the following setup:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} 
\usepackage[authoryear, round, longnamesfirst]{natbib}

\begin{document}
...
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{references}
\nocite{*}
\end{document}
```

The file `references.bib` contains the following entries:

```
@book{13_parking_standards,
author={{The Planning Service}}
title={Parking Standards},
note={www.planningni.gov.uk/downloads/parking-standards.pdf},
urldate={2015-9-24},
institution={The Planning Service},
pages={2}
}

@misc{5_motiondetector,
author={{Vernier Software \& Technology}}
title={Motion Detector 2}
note={http://www.vernier.com/files/manuals/md-btd.pdf},
}
```

However, the output contains the following:

The Planning Service
Vernier Software & Technology

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You're missing commas at the ends of both `author` fields. In the second entry, you're also missing a comma at the end of the `title` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your setup:

- First and foremost, you're missing commas at the ends of the `author` fields of both entries, as well as at the end of the `title` field of the second entry.
- Since you're using the `plainnat` bibliography style, you could make use of the fact that it recognizes a field named `url`; thus, use the `url` field instead of the `note` field for the two URL strings.
- Unfortunately, the `plainnat` bibliography style does *not* recognize a field named `urldate`. If you do wish to show the date the entry was retrieved, you should change the field from

  ```
  urldate={2015-9-24},
  ```

  to

  ```
  note={Retrieved on 2015-9-24},
  ```
- And, do make sure to load the `url` package in the preamble. Doing so will allow LaTeX to find line breaks (if needed) in the two long URL strings. In both entries, allowing line breaks inside the URL strings will indeed be needed.

By the way: Kudos for encasing both `author` fields in double curly braces, to ensure that BibTeX will recognize them as "corporate" authors.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@book{13_parking_standards,
author={{The Planning Service}},
title={Parking Standards},
url={www.planningni.gov.uk/downloads/parking-standards.pdf},
note={Retrieved on 2015-9-24},
institution={The Planning Service},
pages={2}
}
@misc{5_motiondetector,
author={{Vernier Software \& Technology}},
title={{Motion Detector 2}},
url={http://www.vernier.com/files/manuals/md-btd.pdf},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage[authoryear, round, longnamesfirst]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```